# replace simple pattern with sequential next line from another file

Tags: regular-expression, replace

My file `working.txt` has 1000's of lines, which repeat in a simple pattern as follows:

```
name
date_ax
name
date_cd
name
date_ed
name
date_dc
...etc
```

I need to replace each instance of `name` with the sequential next line from another file called `other.txt`, such that each line of `other.txt` is looped through for each replacement of `name`.

`other.txt` file content looks like this:

```
namedewqdwq
name32321321
name3434243gf
nameewqewqeeq
```

After the replacement my working text file `working.txt` would look like this:

```
namedewqdwq
date_ax
name32321321
date_cd
name3434243gf
date_ed
nameewqewqeeq
date_dc
...etc
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list with the entries of the second file and then use [`remove()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#remove%28%29) in an expression to pop the first item of the list for every match.

For example:

```
:let replacements = readfile('other.txt')
:%s/^name$/\=remove(replacements, 0)/
```

See also:

- [`readfile()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#readfile%28%29), which reads the contents of the file into a List.
- [`:help sub-replace-expression`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression), using `\=` at the start of the `:substitute` replacement in order to evaluate a Vimscript expression to determine the contents of the replacement.

Comment: thanks :) appreciated. That works very well.